# Storing serial data onto a text file using Python

Tags: python, arduino

I'm using the following Python code to store the data I receive from the accelerometer MMA7361L. The file is created but without any data being written?

I need to store the data onto the file to prevent loss of data. The data is sent by an Arduino, as my microcontroller, that connects my accelerometer.

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

for i in range(0, 10):
    abc=open('abc.txt', 'r+b')  //append and binary(a+b) mode
    x = port.read(size=1)//   1 byte
    print x
    abc.write(x)
    abc.close()

port.close()
```

Comment: The code that you're displaying is opening the file in `r+b` mode, not `a+b` mode as the comment indicates. Also, giving a binary file a 'txt' extension is confusing at the very least.

Comment: sorry.. was trying something and forgot to change b4 i uploaded.. thank you anyways!

Answer (score 4):

```
import serial

addr  = 'COM4'
baud  = 9600
fname = 'accel.dat'
fmode = 'ab'
reps  = 10

with serial.Serial(addr,baud) as port, open(fname,fmode) as outf:
    for i in range(reps):
        x = port.read(size=1)
        print x
        outf.write(x)
        outf.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the file mode to 'ab' and it should work. a+b is only useful if you also want to read the contents while you are appending data to it.

Unless you need serious optimizations here it's easier to read the whole file at the beginning and then just append data to it reopening it with the 'ab' mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it this way, I am doing in this way for right now and it works. I also have another one where it tells you what com ports are being used and if the *com port* exists to run the `while loop` and if not, to close the file.

```
import serial
import csv

file = raw_input('Save File As: ')
saveFile = open(file, 'w')

serialport = raw_input('Enter Port: ')
port1 = serialport

print "Connecting to....", port1

arduino = serial.Serial(port1, 9600)

print "Arduino detected"

while True: 
    time.sleep(.01)
    data = arduino.readline()
    saveFile.write(data)
    print data
```